# Consulta del mayor número de ventas por cada vendedor

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

estoy haciendo una consulta en Mysql en dónde solo me están proporcionando una tabla con la siguiente info.

id_empleado| id_sucursal| tot_ventas| clientes_atendidos| clientes_satisfechos etc etc

Con un sin fin de registros, buen el chiste es que me piden hacer una consulta que muestre cual de los empleados de cada sucursal vendio la mayor cantidad de productos, cabe resaltar que solo tengo una tabla.

Intenté con la siguiente sentencia.

```
select MAX(ventas) FROM info GROUP BY id_sucursal
```

[image: consulta]

Esta me regresa la lista de el empleado de cada sucursal que vendió más, sin embargo no se como mostrar también su demás información (su id de empleado y su id de sucursal etc)

Intenté con esta sentencia

```
select MAX(ventas), id_sucursal, id_empleado, clientes_atendidos FROM 
info GROUP BY id_sucursal
```

Sin embargo investigando, id_sucursal, id_empleado no estan asociadas al maximo que deseo encontrar, es decir que al concatenarse esta información no coincide, habia pensado también en un inner pero tengo entendido que solo aplica si se tienen 2 tablas. Ayuuda porfa

Comment: Añade todos esos campos al `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con que hagas una simple subconsulta y después aproveches uno de los comportamientos básicos de `Group By` el cual si hay mas de 1 linea de datos al ejecutar la consulta, te mostrara el primero solo, por lo tanto:

1. Lo primero es ordenar para que el los que mas ventas tengas sea el que se muestre, no hace falta que este agrupados, basta con que estén ordenado por `ventas` ya se engargara el `Group By` del resto:

   ```
   SELECT * from info ORDER BY tot_ventas DESC
   ```
2. Ahora al hacer un `Group BY` de esta consulta, solo recogera el primero de cada sucursal y como estan ordenador por `ventas` lo que te mostrara sera el empleado que mas ha vendido, por lo tanto:

   ```
   SELECT id_empleado, id_sucursal, tot_ventas
      FROM ( SELECT * from info ORDER BY tot_ventas DESC) as ordenado
      GROUP BY id_sucursal
   ```

Answer (score 4):

> Te comento que deberías hacerlo con un `INNER` `JOIN`

Puesto que noto tu información esta distribuida en mas una de una tabla; te dejo un ejemplo aproximado a tu escenario para guiarte en la comprensión de como resolver dicha necesidad

**Muestra de código (a través de un ejemplo)**

```
CREATE TABLE empleado(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE sucursal(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  empleado_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_sucursal_empleado FOREIGN KEY(empleado_id) REFERENCES empleado(id) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE ventas(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  empleado_id INT NOT NULL,
  sucursal_id INT NOT NULL,
  tot_ventas INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_ventas_empleado FOREIGN KEY(empleado_id) REFERENCES empleado(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ventas_sucursal FOREIGN KEY(sucursal_id) REFERENCES sucursal(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO empleado(name) VALUES("daniel"), ("pedro"), ("maria"), ("jose");

INSERT INTO sucursal(name, empleado_id)
VALUES
("norte", 1),
("sur", 2),
("este", 3),
("oeste", 3),
("matriz", 1);

INSERT INTO ventas(empleado_id, sucursal_id, tot_ventas)
VALUES
(1, 1, 3000),
(1, 1, 4000),
(2, 2, 200),
(3, 4, 30),
(4, 2, 300),
(4, 1, 3000),
(2, 1, 5000),
(1, 5, 3000),
(1, 3, 10000);
```

Una vez que tienes las tablas y la data disponible, ahora es momento de hacer la query.

**EXPLICACIÓN**

> Hacemos un `INNER JOIN` por que con el obtenemos el listado de usuarios
>   que si tienen ventas registradas y también el id de la sucursal donde
>   han realizado dicha venta. Colocamos la función de agregación `MAX` por
>   que con ella obtendremos solo una nueva fila con el registro del
>   maximo que un empleado ha vendido. hacemos el `join` primero con la
>   tabla sucursal por que un empleado puede estar asociado a una sucursal
>   y posteriormente hacemos el `JOIN` con la tabla ventas por que es aquí
>   donde guardaremos tanto la llave primaria de empleado y sucursal;
>   entendiendo que un empleado puede hacer múltiples ventas tanto en la
>   misma sucursal como en otra distinta

```
SELECT empleado.name AS empleado, sucursal.name AS sucursal, MAX(ventas.tot_ventas) as Maximo
FROM empleado
JOIN sucursal
ON empleado.id = sucursal.empleado_id
JOIN ventas
ON empleado.id = ventas.empleado_id;
```

La cual me devuelve como resultado

```
+----------+----------+------------------------+
| empleado | sucursal | Maximo                 |
+----------+----------+------------------------+
| daniel   | norte    |             10000      |
+----------+----------+------------------------+
```

**EJEMPLO FUNCIONANDO**

En el siguiente link te dejo un ejemplo totalmente funcional para que corrobores como se ejecuta

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d2804/1

Ahora si necesitas mostrar el listado de usuarios con su máximo de ventas, puedes hacer lo siguiente con `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT empleado.name AS empleado, sucursal.name AS sucursal, MAX(ventas.maximo_ventas)
FROM empleado
JOIN sucursal
ON empleado.id = sucursal.empleado_id
JOIN ventas
ON empleado.id = ventas.empleado_id
GROUP BY empleado.name
ORDER BY ventas.maximo_ventas DESC;
```

Con un resultado similar al siguiente

```
+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| empleado | sucursal | MAX(ventas.maximo_ventas) |
+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| daniel   | norte    |             10000         |
| pedro    | sur      |              5000         |
| maria    | este     |                30         |
+----------+----------+---------------------------+
```

**¿Cómo obtengo los valores de las otras tablas?**

> Si te das cuenta uso la sintáxis de `nombreTabla.nombreColumna` para
>   obtener los nombres de las otras columnas que requiero; es decir si
>   quiero el nombre de la sucursal hago lo siguiente
>   `sucursal.nombreSucursal` el código final dependerá de cuales sean los
>   nombres de tus tablas y el nombre de cada una de sus columnas

**Asignando alias**

Una vez que haz obtenido los nombres de las columnas que deseas puedes asignarles un nombre temporal; mira el siguiente ejemplo

1. `MAX(ventas.maximo_ventas)` devolverá una columna con el nombre `MAX(ventas.maximo_ventas)`

Lo que podemos hacer para mejorar la presentación es lo siguiente

1. `MAX(ventas.maximo_ventas) AS 'total_ventas'` devolverá una columna con el nombre `total_ventas`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, lo ideal hubiera sido que efectivamente, yo tenga la libertad de distribuir esas tablas de esa manera, lamentablemente fue parte de un test, los registros de la única tabla que me proporcionan son mas de 20000, por lo que no tenia tanta libertad para separarla, y solo podía hacer uso de esa tabla, sin embargo fue muy detallada y precisa tu respuesta. Mil gracias

Comment: @ChinaON de nada saludos